# Spring MVC launch multiple onsubmit thread every 5 minutes

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

First of all, I apologize for my english, I will try to do my best.

Generaly, I find solutions to all my problems on this site, but this time, it seems that I'm the only one who encountered this problem ... So I decided to register, and ask my question.

I have a `SimpleFormController`, associated with a jsp page. My onSubmit method can be prety huge (save many DAO into database, etc), depending on the user action. The problem I encounter, is that when the on submit last more than 5 minutes (approximately), a new onSubmit instance is launched in a new thread, and this never finish ...

When my onSubmit last less than 5 minutes, everything is fine.

Is there a kind of "timeout" ? Can it be configurable ? I didn't find any isues conresponding to my problem.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: man, 5 minutes for a synchronous request??

Comment: Yes, I know it's long, but it can create a lot of data (thousands of objects, and even more) ... The long part is the saving action into the database, building the new objects only takes several seconds.

Comment: dude, I would be worried if my requests took 5 seconds, what can I say about 5 minutes.

Comment: If you have a way to save thousands of complex objects with Hibernate within 5 seconds, I will be the happiest man in the world. But for now, sometimes it takes me more than 5 minutes and I have to deal with it ... and this "limit" prevents me from doing what I want.

Comment: I mean, have you considered handling those requests asynchronously? Would it be possible in your setup?

Comment: My bad, I didn't think to do the save actions asynchronously ... I have just tried by creating a separate thread to do the job, with a wait message on the page, and it works perfectly. Thank you Abel, that way is much more better !